# how is windows client in C# running in background using GUI controls

Tags: c#, windows

I am new to Windows programming and trying to understand a client written in C#. This client listens to messages from a server and handles them. In this case, it is using C# application, forms and controls that I don't understand. Following is a sample code snippet. It creates an application context that I believe gets called when form is closed. It then connects to a server which sends this client messages and the callbackInterface is used to handle those messages. It creates a form and runs the application with the context created earlier. I believe this part runs a message loop until the form is closed.

Now I am trying to understand what is the point of creating these application context and forms and how they are being used in this case. Can someone help me understand the flow of things here and what role is played by these GUI controls? The client runs entirely in the background with no GUI interface. What is the advantage of using these controls over having a typical client application without these controls that just polls for server messages in a loop?

```
void start() {
// get application context
context = new ApplicationContext();

// connect to a server
connect(name, callbackInterface,...);

// creates a form
cform = new Form();
cform.createControl();
int dummy = cform.Handle.ToInt32();

Application.run(context);

// message loop has returned
disconnect(...)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When designing WinForms it easy to put lots of code in the code-behind. Sometimes a lot of business logic gets buried there. Not a recommended practice but it can be common. If you had such a form and wanted to reuse the business logic but didn't need the GUI you might take the approach you're seeing. Just a guess, but there's not enough detail in your question to do much more.

Comment: I guess my question is does using Win Form objects help in writing a client/server application if you don't need the GUI?

Comment: Depends on if the form controls in use have some functionality that is uniquely useful to solving the specific problem in question.